# Java not allowing me to use anything under java.nio?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nio

For some reason i get this error when trying to access anything under java.nio it throws an error? i have looked for anything of this but i cant find anything and i need to write some files.

If anyone knows anything of this and knows how to fix it, please help!

[image]

Comment: which jdk version are you using

Comment: change your project language level

Comment: @StinePike The very latest Java 8u74

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I cant do that in intelliJ, im referencing JDK 8 via folder path

Comment: You need to make sure the Project Settings show the correct language level - you can be using JDK8 and have a language level set to 6 which would cause something like this.

Comment: @cjstehno its set to 8

Comment: It's annoying when that happens. I suggest you (File->) Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it